# Powershell - passing a switch to a scriptmethod

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

so you can pass a switch to a function:

function func ($parm1,$parm2,[switch]$switch1) {write-host $switch1}

func -switch1

True

How do you pass a switch to a scriptmethod ?

$obj = New-Object Object

Add-Member -in $obj ScriptMethod 'method' { param($parm1,$parm2,[switch]$switch1)
   write-host $switch1
   }

$obj.method(-switch1)  # doesn't work

Comment: functions are modelled after powershell cmdlets (well, kind of) and script methods are modelled after .net methods. You do not use switch parameters in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Switch parameters holds a Boolean value, if the target argument of the method accepts a bool, pass the switch variable:

```
$obj.method($switch1)
```

Comment: Thanks Shay, but that doesn't exactly solve it - nice thing about switches (in functions at least) is that they don't have to all be specified in the call or appear in order. Think that you might have several positional parms (non-switches), then several switch parms that serve as optional values. All the switches default to False unless you specify one. You can skip the regular parms if they're not needed, perhaps they were optional too, and just specify one or more switches if they're needed.

Comment: In the original example the param statement was: param($parm1,$parm2,[switch]$switch1).   func -switch  doesn't care to specify values for parm1 & parm2, only wants to say switch1 is True.  $obj.method($switch)  would pass that value to parm1. I'd have to make sure all the params were passed and values set - $obj.method($parm1,$parm2,$switch1). Hope that clarifies the desire for switches to scriptmethods.